# How to merge base class by Proguard

Tags: java, proguard

I have configuration classes which define the behaviour of the application. If no configuration class extend another one then unused ones are removed by Proguard and the code is optimized effectively. But if one extends the other then both configuration is kept and the code isn't optimized.

```
interface ConfInterface {
    boolean method();
}

class ConfNever implements ConfInterface {
    public boolean method() {
        return false;
    }
}

final class Conf extends ConfNever {
    public boolean method() {
        return true;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test(new Conf());
    }
}

class Test {
    Test(ConfInterface ci) {
        if( ci.method() ) {
            System.out.println("Print");
        } else {
            System.out.println("PrintNever");
        }
    }
}
```

Proguard configuration:

```
-injars  bin/
-outjars out/
-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/rt.jar
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-keep public class Main {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
-optimizationpasses 50
```

Compiled, obfuscated and decompiled Test class:

```
final class c {
    c(final a a) {
        super();
        if (a.a()) {
            System.out.println("Print");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("PrintNever");
    }
}
```

If Conf class doesn't extend ConfNever then ConfNever is removed by Proguard and Test class is optimized to (note: I disabled '-optimizationpasses 50' to keep Test class):

```
final class b {
    b(final a a) {
        super();
        System.out.println("Print");
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make Proguard to merge Conf and ConfNever or to detect that Test class is only initialized with Conf object and optimize accordingly?

Update: I tried '-optimizations "class/merging/vertical"' but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

ProGuard currently won't merge this class hierarchy. It would have to remove `ConfNever#method()`, which its merging criteria currently prevent. The criteria would have to be refined to check that this method is never called from the subclass `Conf`.